# Cannot import module after turning into exe with pyinstaller

Tags: python, module, exe, pyinstaller

I have compiled my python code to .exe using pyinstaller with the command:

```
pyinstaller --onefile .\mycode.py
```

It finished without errors but when I try to use the .exe it it gives me the error:

```
RuntimeError: Cannot import module **** which is needed to continue
```

while *** is a module that is definitly installed (when i run mycode.py using python it works fine) and of course is imported in the code. how can i fix it? Thanks for the helpers.

Comment: Have a look at hidden imports: https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/when-things-go-wrong.html#listing-hidden-imports

Comment: @MauriceMeyer thanks for the reply, I am declaring the module with regular import declaration, i am using eval() though which did not seem to matter when i compiled another script, I've tried to add to the command --hidden-import=*** which did not solve the issue. any other suggestions?

Comment: @MauriceMeyer that link is out of date! It hasn't been updated in 4 years, and 6 versions! Please use PyInstaller.readthedocs.io instead.

Comment: @prophet-five we can't help unless we know what that module is or enough about it. Is it pure python, C compiled, etc.

Comment: hi @Legorooj, it is pure python, since it's from work I can't say much about it. It seems that the problem was that it uses importlib.import_module, a simple import on my script seems to solve this

Answer (score 0):

As the comment on the question from the OP says, they were using `importlib`. PyInstaller can only read imports using the `from *** import ***` or the `import ***` format. If you'd like to use `importlib`, `__import__` or any other unsupported method, please add the imports to hiddenimports with the `--hidden-import=***` option. This option can be used multiple times.